# D3 svg map renders over top of other html elements with IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js, svg

Hi I have made a D3 map showing a journey [here](https://sallyfl.github.io/OskarSpeck_D3Map/). It works as expected in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox browsers that I have tested it on but I have a problem with IE. The svg map renders over the top of my header as in this pic: [image]I have tried including `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`in the head of my index.html but this hasn't made any difference. I'm not sure what to research to find a solution to this problem. Can anyone please advise me what to do to correct this?

Comment: Compare the css display property of svg elements...other browsers default svg elements with display:inline, IE with display:block... you could add the css style rule... svg{display:inline} so that all web browsers use the same display rule.